# I want product name and quantity in textbox

Tags: javascript, list, textbox, product, addition

[I want product and price to be shown in textbox when someone select any product](https://codepen.io/salman2206/pen/gOWvrwm)

var a = document.getElementsByClassName(" pname").innerHTML;

var b = document.getElementsByClassName("increase").addEventListener("click",myFunction);

var c = document.getElementById("test");

function  myFunction (){

```
c.append (a.innerHTML);
```

}

Comment: your question with respect to provided code is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't realy understand what is your question but be aware that `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLcollection. HTMLCollection have no `innerHTML` property nor `addEventListener` method. You need to, either loop over all elements in the collection or use `document.querySelector` which returns the first element it finds

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are trying to achieve this

```
<button onclick="myFunction(productName, value)">Product</button>

<input id="textbox" type="text">
```

```
myFunction(name, value) {
document.getElementById('textbox').value = name +' '+ value ;
}
```

Comment: you can also create dynamic products and bind onclick with dynamic paramters for multiple products.